# $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:xy=1\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

To check which pairs are Homeomorphic?

A.$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:xy=0\}$

B.$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:xy=1\}$

C.$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:xy=0,x+y\geq0\}$

D.$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:xy=1,x+y\geq 0\}$

I think A and B are not homeomorphic as A is connected while B is not.But I cant say about C and D.Am I right ?Please help

Comment: You have made pictures of what the sets look like?

Comment: C and D are homeomorphic. They are not homeomorphic to B (which is disconnected), nor to $A$ (which has a point the removal of which leaves four connected components.

Comment: Yes @HennoBrandsma I have drawn them

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is a cross of lines (so indeed connected), and $B$ is two disjoint closed parts so indeed disconnected.

$C$ is basically a line as well, with a sharp corner: the part of $A$ that has $x \ge 0$ or $y \ge 0$. Can you find a homeomorphism with $\mathbb{R}$?

$D$ is also basically a line, as it's one half of $B$. Can you find a homeomorphism with $\mathbb{R}$?

To see that $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic or not: what happens if you remove the origin from $A$. And what happens if you remove any point from $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer

Comment: @learnmore Happy to help!